# gerrit and apache2 config issue

Tags: git, apache, gerrit

GERRIT Config : Config for gerrit
....................................

```
 [gerrit]
 basePath = git

        canonicalWebUrl = [a link] http://54.193.35.113:8080

[database]

        type = mysql
        hostname = localhost
        database = reviewdb
        username = gerrit
[auth]

        type = HTTP

[sendemail]

        smtpServer = localhost

[container]

        user = gerrit
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]

        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]

        listenUrl = http://*:8081/
[cache]

        directory = cache
```

.................................

Apache2 HTTPD CONFIG

```
<IfDefine DEFAULT_VHOST>
Listen 8081
NameVirtualHost *:8081

<VirtualHost *:8081>
        ServerName [a link]54.193.35.113
        Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/default_vhost.include

        <IfModule mpm_peruser_module>
                ServerEnvironment apache apache
        </IfModule>

        ProxyRequests Off
        <proxy *="">
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </proxy>

        ProxyPass /gerrit/ [a link]http://54.193.35.113:8080/gerrit/
        ProxyPassReverse /gerrit/ http://54.193.35.113:8080/gerrit/

        <Location /gerrit/login/>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
                AuthBasicProvider file
                AuthUserFile /var/www/54.193.35.113/passwords
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
```

......................................

Error

When i open [a link] `http://54.193.35.113:8081` . It redirects to [a link] `http://54.193.35.113:8081/login/`

The HTTP server did not provide the username in the Authorization header when it forwarded the request to Gerrit Code Review.

If the HTTP server is Apache HTTPd, check the proxy configuration includes an authorization directive with the proper location, ensuring it ends with '/':

```
 <VirtualHost [a link]54.193.35.113:8081>
        ServerName [a link]54.193.35.113

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Proxy *>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        <Location /login/>
          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
          Require valid-user
          ...
        </Location>


        AllowEncodedSlashes On
        ProxyPass / http://.../ nodecode
    </VirtualHost>
```

................................

I think i am not sure how apache, tomcat and gerrit works together. I am a developer not a system admin but trying to set up all servers.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have not be able to get it to work unless I use http authentication for the whole gerrit site, in you case `/gerrit/` instead of the `/login/`, see [the http digest authentication](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-sso.html#_http_basic_digest_authentication)

Also check the [reverse proxy doc](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-reverseproxy.html) as your reverse proxy setup is also wrong.

Comment: This is fixed in Gerrit 2.8 with the refactorings of the HTTP auth method, but for <= 2.7, we always included the following change in our builds to enable anonymous browsing (as seen on http://review.typo3.org): https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/gerrit/commit/3616ad6a9c9102a005e1f63365b404a77e395174